# iOS WebRTC mesh video conference call memory increasing issue

Tags: ios, webrtc, conference, mesh-network, webrtc-ios

[image]**Issue:**
I am working on iOS WebRTC mesh conference call of 4 persons and after running video conference call of 5 or 6 minutes, memory size is increasing and whole application becomes hang.

**Scenario:**
4 persons conference calls for only audio or only video(without audio) is working fine.
but facing memory size increasing issue with 4 person on video conference call.

**What we are doing:**

1. We are using very low bit rates and frames and default video codec.

Profiler screen shot:

Using below configuration for 4 persons:
Minimum bit rate: 10000
Maximum bit rate: 40000
Current bit rate: 20000

We are using lowest resolution of the device via:

```
 private func startCapturer(frontCamera:AVCaptureDevice, capturer:RTCCameraVideoCapturer) {
        let fps = 15
        let options = RTCCameraVideoCapturer.supportedFormats(for: frontCamera)
            var supportable = (options.sorted { (f1, f2) -> Bool in
                let width1 = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(f1.formatDescription).width
                let width2 = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(f2.formatDescription).width
                return width1 < width2
            }).first! 
        capturer.startCapture(with: frontCamera,
                              format: supportable,
                              fps: fps)
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to these links for better understanding:

[Users in WebRTC call](https://bloggeek.me/how-many-users-webrtc-call/)

and for the performance evaluation please follow the document:

[Performance evaluation for WebRTC](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323950925_Performance_Evaluation_of_WebRTC-based_Video_Conferencing)

Comment: When memory size is increasing then we are getting logs like:- 
[RTCCameraVideoCapturer captureOutput:didDropSampleBuffer:fromConnection:]): Dropped sample buffer. Reason: OutOfBuffers

Comment: The link you can follow for understanding the error log you are getting: 
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1388468-captureoutput?language=objc

Comment: Is there ant way, We can clear and manage that buffer.

Comment: Please follow the proper guideline and tutorial in this link:   https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/